# triggering hover event on array of elements when any one element is hovered

Tags: jquery, arrays, hover

I am working on a rating system. I have to highlight all the stars till the star hovered upon.
My dom is like this:

```
    <div class="star">
                 <i class="fa rating-star" ></i><!-- 
                 --><i class="fa rating-star" ></i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" ></i><!-- 
                 --><i class="fa rating-star" ></i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" ></i><!-- 
                 --><i class="fa rating-star" ></i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" ></i><!-- 
                 --><i class="fa rating-star" ></i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" ></i><!-- 
                 --><i class="fa rating-star" ></i>
     </div>
```

Now suppose one hover upon the star numbered 8, so I have to highlight all the stars till eighth star.
using this css:

```
.rating-star{
cursor: pointer;
}
.rating-star:hover{
color: #ffcc00;
}
```

using this js but I am getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var halfStarArray = $('.star i');
    $('.star i').mouseover(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            $(halfStarArray[i]).trigger('mouseenter');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You have binded mouseover event and triggering mouseenter event explicityly which is calling your binded event and getting into infinite loop.
You can have an `hover` event where add and remove your hovering class to the previous elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var halfStarArray = $('.star i');
    $('.star i').hover(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
       //add class to all previous li elements using `lt` selector
       $('.star i:lt(' + index + ')').addClass('rating-star-hover');
       $(this).addClass('rating-star-hover');
    }, function() {
      var index = $(this).index();
      //remove class from all previous li elements using `lt` selector
      $('.star i:lt(' + index + ')').removeClass('rating-star-hover');
      $(this).removeClass('rating-star-hover');
    });
});
```

```css
.rating-star{
cursor: pointer;
}
.rating-star-hover{
color: #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star">
                 <i class="fa rating-star" >11</i><i class="fa rating-star" > 22 </i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" >12</i><i class="fa rating-star" > 33 </i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" >13</i><i class="fa rating-star" > 44 </i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" >14</i><i class="fa rating-star" > 55 </i>
                <i class="fa rating-star" >15</i><i class="fa rating-star" > 66 </i>
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks @Bhushan Kawadkar for giving me this insight. I got little curious and measured the time interval using performance.now() your method is faster than the array method that I was using.

Comment: happy to help you :), here we don't have to iterate through all elements hence it is faster. You can upvote and accept the answer if find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
.rating-star {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .rating-star-hover {
            color: #ffcc00;
        }

 <div class="star">
        <i class="fa rating-star">0</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">1</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">2</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">3</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">4</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">5</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">6</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">7</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">8</i>
        <i class="fa rating-star">9</i>
    </div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var halfStarArray = $('.star i');

            $('.star i').mouseover(function () {
                var found = false;
                for (var i = 0; i <= halfStarArray.length; i++) {
                    if (found)
                        break;
                    else {
                        $(halfStarArray[i]).addClass('rating-star-hover');
                        if (halfStarArray[i] === this)
                            found = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.star i').mouseout(function () {
                halfStarArray.removeClass('rating-star-hover');
            });

        });
    </script>
```